# how to calculate the time in the hr:min:sec

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can some one help me out from the time calculation in form of hr:min:sec. But I does need the system time. That's for I made this code

I try to make time calculation in the form of hr:min:sec
but it doesn't work in right way(it work till one hours)&
((1)after the 60 second output is 0:1:60 (2)after the 61 second output is 0:1:71 (3)after after the 3600 second output is 1:1:00 but(3)after the 3601 second output is wrong )

Here is the code:

In the .m file

```
-(IBAction)start
{      
    timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(.01) target:self selector:@selector(timepassed) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];        
}

-(void)timepassed
{
     counter++;
    if(sec==60)
        sec=0;
    else 
        sec=counter/100;

    if(min==60)
        min=0;
    else 
        min=sec/60;

    if(hr==24)
        hr=0;
    else 
        hr=min/60;

    m1++;
    NSString *l=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%i:%i",hr,min,sec];

    [m setText:l];
}
```

Comment: NSTimers are not accurate enough to do what you're trying to do here, I would recommend not using them for this purpose.

Comment: I agree with Joshua.  Instead, use an NSDate to record the start time, and then call timeIntervalSinceNow on it to see how much time has passed.

Comment: I agree that diff'ing timestamps is much more accurate. But then, this method assures you get a continuos counter that won't miss a heartbeat. This may or may not be a good thing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) timepassed
{
    counter++;
    if (counter == 60)  { secs++; counter = 0; }
    if (secs == 60) { min++; secs = 0; }
    if (min == 60) { hr++; min = 0; }

    // Your usual output here
}
```

Keep in mind that this sets the counter variable different than your code, i.e. it stores only 1/100 secs from 0...99.

There are of cause a dozen of algorithms to translate times into hrs:mins:secs, this is just one of them that's similar to your code.

Side note: Please accept answers that did help you (also on your older questions), this is common behavior on this site and keeps people motivated to help you.